# Flex Channel Security Error while logging into two different domains from single app

Tags: apache-flex, security, flash, dns, channel

i need to connect to two different domains from a single flex application.
the problem is the domain other than the current hosted domain is unable to login.

letz say i hosted the application at LOCAL server. im able to login to the local server .
From the existing application i need a login to the MAIN server too. The problem comes up here.

flash security is not allowing login to MAIN server.
in crossdomain we allow-access-from MAIN server. but i want access to the MAIN server from LOCAL server.

is ther nything i need to put extra in crossdomain.xml ?

plz i need a solution!!

ThnQ
Sris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a crossdomain.xml on your "MAIN" server and allow-access-from "LOCAL"; you don't need to put a crossdomain.xml on the server where your SWF is hosted. The cross domain file is intended to be placed on a 3rd party server to indicate that SWFs hosted from particular domains have permission to access its services.

Another short explanation is here:

http://www.flexafterdark.com/docs/Flash-CrossDomain

Comment: hi brd6644
thanx 4 d response.
i did it as u said
i got an exception saying:  Security sandbox violation ..
 swf file at LOCAL server cud not load MAIN server's crossdomain.xml 

i used the crossdomain.xml as follows:

   public function initApp():void
   {
     Security.allowDomain( "remoteservername" );
      
     Security.loadPolicyFile( "http://remoteservername:8080/main/crossdomain.xml" );
      
    var request:URLRequest = 
    new URLRequest( "http://remoteservername:8080/main/crossdomain.xml" );
    
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.load( request );
}